# How to integrate Zoom Sdk in flutter app i am getting error while using flutter_zoom_sdk

Tags: java, flutter, zoom-sdk

i want to integrate zoom sdk in flutter application for that purpose i tried `flutter_zoom_sdk` package but when i add it in the pubspec.yaml file and run the command

```
flutter pub run flutter_zoom_sdk:unzip_zoom_sdk
```

and try to run the application (without writing any code just adding this package to the pubspec.yaml) i am getting these errors and the app is not running

> Errors

```
/home/munsif/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_zoom_sdk-1.1.0+4/android/src/main/java/com/evilratt/flutter_zoom_sdk/StatusStreamHandler.java:27: error: incompatible types: MeetingServiceListener is not a functional interface
        statusListener = (meetingStatus, errorCode, internalErrorCode) -> {
                         ^
    multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface MeetingServiceListener
/home/munsif/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_zoom_sdk-1.1.0+4/android/src/main/java/com/evilratt/flutter_zoom_sdk/FlutterZoomSdkPlugin.java:225: error: cannot find symbol
      zoomSDK.loginWithZoom(options.get("userId"), options.get("userPassword"));
             ^
  symbol:   method loginWithZoom(String,String)
  location: variable zoomSDK of type ZoomSDK
/home/munsif/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_zoom_sdk-1.1.0+4/android/src/main/java/com/evilratt/flutter_zoom_sdk/FlutterZoomSdkPlugin.java:366: error: cannot find symbol
      zoomSDK.loginWithZoom(options.get("userId"), options.get("userPassword"));
             ^
  symbol:   method loginWithZoom(String,String)
  location: variable zoomSDK of type ZoomSDK
3 errors

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:: AAPT: aapt2 W 05-23 21:40:19 128162 128162 LoadedArsc.cpp:682] Unknown chunk type '200'.
     error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationRailView (aka com.edutrainia.user:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationRailView) not found.
     error: failed linking references.
3

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_zoom_sdk:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

and after searching for the error and making changes in the java files of the package the other three errors are gone and getting only this error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:: AAPT: aapt2 W 05-23 21:40:19 128162 128162 LoadedArsc.cpp:682] Unknown chunk type '200'.
> error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationRailView (aka com.edutrainia.user:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationRailView) not found.
> error: failed linking references.